SQL join, display multiple values into one row
If I have the following tables (just an example):
table1:



id
tax year




1
2000


1
2001


2
2001



table2:



id
tax year
value




1
2000
a


1
2000
b


1
2000
c



How would I join the two tables so I can display multiple values into one row like this?



id
tax year
value




1
2000
a,b,c


1
2001
---


2
2001
---



I am using db2 so I'm not able to use some functions such as GROUP_CONCAT(). Would LIST_AGG() be an option? Or is there a way to have a nested select statement and somehow concatenate the results, something like this?
select
 id
,concat((select value
  from database.table2 tab2
  join database.table1 tab1
  on tab1.id=tab2.id))
from database.table1


Don't spam tags! Only tag the RDBMS you use. I removed the other tags.

See the documentation about LISTAGG: https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-aggregate-functions/db2-listagg/

Hi - if you think LISTAGG is an option then what’s stopping you trying it?

You can use LISTAGG() as shown below:
select a.id, a.tax_year,
  listagg(b.value, ',') within group (order by b.value) as value
from table1 a
left join table2 b on b.id = a.id and b.tax_year = a.tax_year
group by a.id, a.tax_year;

Result:
 ID  TAX_YEAR  VALUE 
 --- --------- ----- 
 1   2000      a,b,c 
 1   2001      null  
 2   2001      null  

See running example at db<>fiddle.

Thank you! This works perfectly, I was trying to use listagg but seems my syntax was off.
